# under shell, how to get id of app in "time app"?

Tags: shell, signals

Under shell, when "time app " is issued, then how to get the id of app?

The following seems only to get the shell parent id that calls "time myapp"

##########################
#! /bin/sh

time myapp &
myid = "$!"
##########################

Thanks

when "time myapp", I want to get to know the id of myapp so that I can send signal to it

Comment: I can't replicate this using bash. what shell are you using

Comment: I think if you do this with a shell that does not have `time` builtin, `$!` will be the `time` process itself

Comment: note also that `myid = "$!"` attempts to execute a command called `myid` with two arguments, it does not assign to a variable called `myid`

Answer (score 1):

You can look up the processes with that process ID as parent process ID using `ps`:

```
myappid=$(ps -a -o ppid=,pid= | awk -v ppid="$myid" '$1 == ppid { print $2 }')
```

Using `ps -o ppid,pid` we obtain a two-column table, with parent process ID in the first column and the process ID in the second. Then, we use AWK to print the second column value from the lines which have `$myid` in the first (parent) column.

GNU implementation of `ps` has the ability to restrict by parent process ID built in, so you can just do

```
myappid=$(ps --ppid "$myid" -o pid=)
```

Comment: Using "ps --ppid $$ -o pid --no-headers", manually type in csh terminal, it works as expected; but not in /bin/sh script. What's the reason? I have to use "time" to evoke the app

Comment: In script, "$$" is confirmed to be correct and child id is not extracted correctly.

Comment: mySignalHandle() {
  childId=`ps --ppid "$$" -o pid --no-headers`
  echo " id $$ cld id $childId  "
exit 
}

trap 'mySignalHandle' USR1

Comment: Why are you suddenly using `$$`? Your question had `$!`, the PID of the backgrounded `time app` command. `$$` is the PID of your shell, which is presumably one level above. To prove my code works, try this: `time sleep 1000 & myid=$!; myappid=$(ps --no-header --ppid "$myid" -o pid); ps --no-header -p $myappid -
o command`: it should print `sleep 1000` (the command under `time`). (Sorry I forgot `--no-header`, oopsie... though I believe the `=` trick is more portable.)

Comment: Your code works.  if "time app" is not background but foreground.  How to extract this app id when it's running?

Comment: If it is in foreground, then where are you running the code that is trying to get the PID? Sorry, but this question keeps changing, it is very difficult to pinpoint exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes.  as you known, if backgrounded, it needs "time app&    id=$!    fg   wait".  The original code  is foreground with "time app" and I want to pass signal from this shell into this app with specific id. so I need 'trap "myfunction" USR1.  Background dealing looks somewhat not perfect.

Comment: If a subprocess is active in foreground, then you can't pass signal from this shell, because you can't execute the code in this shell, since it is waiting for the subprocess to finish.